# How do you disable the iOS Storage full alert?

Tags: iphone, ios, storage

I've been getting close to filling up my 16 GB iPhone 4 with iOS 5. I have freed up some space and have 1.5 GB available, but I keep getting alerts that are annoying.

Is there a way to disable the alert or change the threshold for which it is triggered? 
Here's what the alert says.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Apple do not provide any way to stop what it perceives as important alerts.

That said, for those with jailbroken phones, [**popup blocker**](http://modmyi.com/info/popupblocker.php) provides the required functionality

Edit: the original question is answered in the most part, but i think the real question should be 'Why am i getting the ios Stoage almost full" alert.

this is either a bug, or you've got a lot of mail stored on the phone...

There appears to be a few users with the same issue over on the Apple support forums [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3406727?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: Do you know what threshold the space free is triggered at?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a jailbreak issue.  A quick cure would be to, go to notifications; reminders; Alert style: change to none or banners.  I recommend none. Until we get a better fix.